# Knife Bootstrap SSH connection failed with username and password

Tags: azure, chef-infra, knife, configuration-management

I am trying to perform `"knife bootstrap"` for registering my node to the workstation.

I have vm's on azure. (inbound ports are enables)
I am using this command to do the knife bootstrap :

```
"knife bootstrap <public-ip> -U <username> -P <password> --sudo -N <vm-name>"
```

While setting up the ubuntu vm, I set authorization via username and password.

It doesn't let me do the task and the error message is:

```
"WARN: [SSH] connection failed, terminating (#<Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: 
 Authentication failed for user sysadmin@172.174.142.148>)
 ERROR: Train::Transports::SSHFailed: SSH session could not be established"
```

Comment: A bit surprised you auth to Azure VM with a password, don't you need a private key authentification ?